# add event listener is not working in dynamically (*ngFor) created element

Tags: html, angular, typescript

### I am trying to expand this accordion view.

whenever clicking on the section button  this **`userSelection[i].addEventListener`..** event listerner makes the  id become 'open'. so the accordion get expanded.

this is working fine when I not using `*ngFor`. if I used `*ngFor` directive addEventListener is not working.

[image: Attached image for reference]

**not working HTML code:**

```
<div class="accordian" id='accordian'>
        <section class="section">
            <div class="section1" *ngFor='let m of data.accordian.printers'>
                <button class="accordion" (click)='modelpop()'>{{m.type}}
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right closearrow" id='arrowshow'></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-down openarrow" id='arrownotshow'></i>
                    </button>

                <div class="panel" id='close'>
                    <p>menu 1</p>
                    <p>menu 2</p>
                    <p>menu 3</p>
                    <p>menu 4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
 #close {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.accordian {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(244, 244, 244);
    top: 140px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 95%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #00000085;
    padding-bottom: 20px
}

.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 25px;
    width: 250px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-weight: bolder
}
```

**type script:**

```
ngOnInit(){    
var userSelection = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var pane = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');

     for (let i = 0; i < userSelection.length; i++) {
    userSelection[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (pane[i].id == 'open') {
              pane[i].id = 'close';

            } else {
              pane[i].id = 'open';

            }
    })
    }

}
```

**working fine HTML code:**

```
 <section class="section">

    <div class='section1'>
        <button class="accordion" (click)='modelpop()'>Section 1
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right closearrow" id='arrowshow'></i>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down openarrow" id='arrownotshow'></i>
        </button>

        <div class="panel" id='close'>
            <p>menu 1</p>
            <p>menu 2</p>
            <p>menu 3</p>
            <p>menu 4</p>
        </div>
        <div class='section1'>
            <button class="accordion" (click)='modelpop()'>Section 1
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right closearrow" id='arrowshow'></i>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down openarrow" id='arrownotshow'></i>
            </button>

            <div class="panel" id='close'>
                <p>menu 1</p>
                <p>menu 2</p>
                <p>menu 3</p>
                <p>menu 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why do you use addEventListener('click') instead of just using the (click) event binding with Angular ?

Comment: how to specify? 1st button is clicked.. second button is clicked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a simple solution which toggles the visibility of an element on click.

You need not write this much code but just maintain a visibility flag for each item in the array you bind to your list and toggle that flag on each click.

Sample is at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toggle-options

It has a bit of `animations` as well. You can get rid of it by removing the `animations` property from component decorator and the animations trigger from the template

Comment: wow superb... really gr8.. thanks a lot.. y i wanna remove the animation.. its looking pretty good..  thank you.... thanks a lot...